# Only one Signal after every EMA cross

Tags: pine-script

I am new to PineScript and i would like to get only one (the first valid) signal after every EMA Cross.

My plotshape line looks like this and works perfectly, but i get way to many signals.

```
plotshape(ta.crossover(rsi, Lower_Curve) and ta.change(ema) > 0, title = "Buy", text = 'Buy', location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(#4c861c, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
```

I tried something like this but it does not work :(

```
var signal = ta.crossover(close, ema)
var isFirstCross = ta.barssince(signal) == 1
var plotSignal = isFirstCross and ta.crossover(rsi, Lower_Curve) and ta.change(ema) > 0

plotshape(plotSignal, title="Buy", text='Buy', location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(#4c861c, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean that switches from true or false. Using your second example something like this.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

ema= ta.ema(close,8)

signal = ta.crossover(close, ema)
var isFirstCross = false
plotSignal = isFirstCross == false and signal
if plotSignal
    isFirstCross := true
if close < ema
    isFirstCross := false

plot(ema)
plotshape(plotSignal, title="Buy", text='Buy', location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(#4c861c, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
```